# Analysing quantity and membership levels of Facebook groups over the past year

Tags: python, selenium, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I need to analyse the number of Facebook groups created in the past year related to a topic, and their membership numbers over the same period of time.

Currently I have followed a tutorial to scrape Facebook for all groups related to that one keyword using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

your_username = input("Please Enter Your Email/Login")
your_password = input("Please Enter Your Password")
query = input("Please enter a search query")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python34\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
print ("Logging in...")
driver.get("http://facebook.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(your_username)
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys(your_password)
driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
print ("Login Successful!")

driver.get("https://mobile.facebook.com/search/groups/?q=" + query)

import time
time.sleep(2) #Wait for page to load.

check = 0 #Variable to check after each pagination(Scroll Down)
last = 0 #What the last length of group_links was
time_to_sleep = 1 #Total time to sleep after each scroll down.
group_links = [] #A list to store new group links.
while check<10:
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]") # grabs every anchor element on page each loop
    for elem in elems: #Loops through each anchor element above
        new_link = elem.get_attribute("href") #grabs link from anchor element
        if "facebook.com/groups/" in new_link: #Checks to see if facebook group link
            if new_link not in group_links: #If new link found not already in our group links add it
                group_links.append(new_link)

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(time_to_sleep)  # Sleep here, let page scroll load
    if last == len(group_links): #If the amount of group links is the same as last time, then add 1 to check
        print ("Found Same Amount...") 
        check+=1
    else:#Check out http://www.pythonhowto.com
        check=0 #If not reset check back to 0
    last = len(group_links) #changes last to current length of group links
    print ("Total group links found => "),last

print ("Out of Loop")
filey = open("grouplinks.txt","w") #Open file
for link in group_links: #FOr each link found write it to file
    filey.write(link + "\n")
filey.close()
driver.quit() #Exits selenium driver (It can sometimes hang in background)
```

However, this only gives me groups existing today. Is it possible to run something similar to analyse the number of groups created since, lets say 01/01/2017?

Sidenote: I have read that the Facebook Graph API is a more efficient method of carrying out tasks such as this when compared to scraping. Should I be doing this differently?
Lastly; This is for a college project, ultimately what I want to achieve is to be able to compare the number of Facebook groups related to Bitcoin, their memberships over a period of time, and compare this to the price of Bitcoin over the same period.

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely be using the Graph API for something like this.

Comment: If the API provides the data you’re after I’d use the API.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am now using the Graph API and can get information on group memberships.                               
   `code` /v2.11/{GROUP_ID}?fields=members.limit(0).summary(true)    `code`                   /n However, I am still struggling with getting this in the form of data over time. Ideally I would like to be able to show 365 (daily) data points over the past year. Giving the total daily count of membership over that period. Any suggestions/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: _“Sidenote: I have read that the Facebook Graph API is a more efficient method of carrying out tasks such as this when compared to scraping. Should I be doing this differently?”_ - you should not scrape at all, because that is against Facebook’s ToS. _“still struggling with getting this in the form of data over time”_ - pretty sure that data isn’t even available for specific dates. You can only start building your own list of daily values now ... and in 365 days from now, you will have your data “for the last year” ...